# Specifying function return type to be dict's KeysView

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.5, python-3.6, typing

In PyCharm I got the following Python 3 code:

```
def get_dict_keys(d: dict) -> list:
    assert(isinstance(d, dict))
    return d.keys()
```

When inspecting the code I get the following error:

```
Expected type 'list', got 'KeysView' instead
```

I would like to specify the correct return code so as to suppress this warning.

Comment: It's not clear from the question **in which direction** you want to correct that. *Should* that method return a list, in which case it's the code that's wrong not the typing? If the code is correct, does it actually matter if it returns a `KeysView` specifically (rather than e.g. a general `Iterable`)? Frankly that seems like a weird method to have written at all, in the context of [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I would like to keep the code as it is, but fix the warning. I agree with you that specifying `typing.Iterable` is better than `typing.KeysView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to write type hints for keys and items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509647/correct-way-to-write-type-hints-for-keys-and-items)

Comment: Why do you think that `typing.Iterable` is better than `typing.KeysView`? KeysView is better because it have `__contains__`  fo `in` operations (correct me if I wrong) , so it is closer to many usages of dict keys. Of course, in the context of duck typing you don't need any type hints at all.

Answer (score 1):

Python's typing library supports specifying the `Iterable` type:

```
from typing import Iterable

def get_dict_keys(d: dict) -> Iterable:
    assert(isinstance(d, dict))
    return d.keys()
```