# Correct way to write type hints for keys and items

Tags: python, python-typing

I have some Python code and want to add type hints for static type checks. However, I am stuck at annotating the results of `dict.keys`, etc.

Please take a look at the following example:

```
class MyParams:
    _params: dict[str, MyParam]

    def keys(self):  # TODO -> type?
        return self._params.keys()

    def items(self):  # TODO -> type?
        return self._params.items()
```

What are the correct type hint statements for `def keys(self)` and `def items(self)`?

Comment: Did you look in the `typing` docs? It provides e.g. [`KeysView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.KeysView).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `XYZView` types from the `typing` module:

```
import typing

class MyParams:
    _params: dict[str, MyParam]

    def keys(self) -> typing.KeysView[str]:
        return self._params.keys()

    def items(self) -> typing.ItemsView[str, MyParam]:
        return self._params.items()
```

Comment: typing.collections.KeysView was not found in my setup, but typing.KeyView was ok (python 3.6.8)

Comment: @al.zatv
```python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:12:48) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import typing                                                                                       

In [2]: typing.collections.KeysView                                                                         
Out[2]: collections.abc.KeysView

In [3]:  
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.abc.ItemsView](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ItemsView).

[typing.ItemsView](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ItemsView) is deprecated since python 3.9.